# Parenting duplicating and graying out child objects in outliner

Tags: parent-child, parent

I am having an issue all of a sudden when parenting a few objects just added in that they parent but appear to be a duplicate in the hierarchy under the parent and are grayed out. This is using Blender 3.0
[image]

As you can see these last 2 I parented are grayed under parent and still remain below in the collection when they were created. I have been parenting other objects (drag n drop as well as Ctrl P keeping transforms too) just fine until today and have no idea why I am getting these results?

Can someone help me understand why I am now getting these results and how to correct this issue?
TIA!
Rick...

Comment: Well I have resolved this issue on the objects graying out after parenting. Somehow (I do not know how either) the new objects were not apart of the collection. So I tested adding object in the collection and then deleting the collection of an object. I found that I was able to parent the object in the collection to an object already in the collection but doing this with the object not in the collection was in essence "linking" that object into the collection not parenting. Thats my best guess here anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my previous comment resolving my issue at least and maybe this will help others should it happen to them.
Thanks.
Rick...

Comment: You should post that comment here as your answer.